# TeX capacity exceeded involving \q_nil

Tags: errors, expl3, memory

The following complete example (that I'm sorry I didn't succeed to make more minimal) used to compile like a charm (I guess with a not updated TL 2017) but that's not the case anymore:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
>    
>                      \q_nil 
>   l.53 \end{align}

Do you see what happens?

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{autonum}
%
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {flalign,alignat}
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
  \RenewEnviron{#1}{}
}
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {align,multline}
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
  \cs_set_eq:cc {db_#1_start:} {#1}
  \cs_set_eq:cc {db_#1_end:} {end#1}
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{amsmath#1}{}
  {\cs:w db_#1_start:\cs_end:}
  {\cs:w db_#1_end:\cs_end:}
  \RenewEnviron{#1}
  {
    \cs:w db_multiline_eq:nV\cs_end: {#1} \BODY
  }
}
\seq_new:N \l_db_multiline_eq_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \db_multiline_eq:nn
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_db_multiline_eq_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \begin{amsmath#1}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_db_multiline_eq_seq { \multiline@double@backslash }
  \end{amsmath#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \db_multiline_eq:nn { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \db_multiline_double_backslash:n
{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\\*}{\\}
  %
  \db_add_multiline_eq_label:
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiline@double@backslash}{s}{%
  \db_multiline_double_backslash:n {#1}
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \db_add_multiline_eq_label: {}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  e^{i\pi}+1 & = 0 \\
  e          & = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{1}{n!}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for your information, precisely align and multline do have a different behaviour since they grab the whole content inside an argument, so you are not talking about a classic `\foo` and `\endfoo` environment. They are progrmmed to see `\end{foo}` explicitly (IIRC).

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. The complete code adds to multi-line environments (such as `align` and `multline`) that are broken by page breaks a marginal note warning the reader the equation continues on next page. And this complete code used to work for both `align` and `multline`.

Comment: The code doesn't compile for me with texlive 2015, 2016, 2017 and 2018.  The error messages change but I get always an input stack overflow.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ooops, sorry. Still strange error, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't try to debug it -- to late for a combination of environ and amsmath ;-) What is the code meant to do?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Let me know if my comment to Manuel isn't precise enough. The culprit seems to be the `autonum` package.